# Unexpected results from array.map()

Tags: javascript

Very simple question but I couldn't figure why the below code results in NaN in first index?

```js
    var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    var result = arr.map(function(x) {
        if(arr[x] >= 2) {
            return arr[x] + 10;
        } else {
            return arr[x] - 10;
        }
    });

    console.log(result); // [-9, 12, 13, NaN]
```

Comment: `x` is the actual item in the array, not the index.

Comment: arr[x] is invalid.

Comment: x isnt index in map... it is value. So u dont need arr[x] but just x

Comment: OK, that's whay I thought, but when I use `x` instead of bracket notation I still get strange results. Please see for yourself.

Comment: You just changed the question to the correct answer and now it works !!!

Comment: @exception-io Define "strange results".

Comment: I was just unsure why I received a `NaN` as one of the array elements but it looks like I wasn't using `map()` correctly. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array `map` accepts parameter as `(item,index)`. In your case `x` is representing array element which will be 1,2,3,4 and so on. So arr[1] will be first element that is 1, but `arr[4]` will be undefined since there is no element present at the `fifth` index. You can replace `arr[x]` with only `x` or with `arr[index]`

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var result = arr.map(function(x, index) {
  console.log('Array element', x)
  if (arr[index] >= 2) {
    return arr[index] + 10;
  } else {
    return arr[index] - 10;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the callback is set to the element of the array

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var result = arr.map(function(x) {
    if(x >= 2) {
        return x + 10;
    } else {
        return x - 10;
    }
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the index, then in `map` it is second parameter. The first parameter is the array element.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var result = arr.map(function(x, i) {
    if(arr[i] >= 2) {
        return arr[i] + 10;
    } else {
        return arr[i] - 10;
    }
});

console.log(result); // [12, 13, 14, NaN]
```

But, there is no necessity of `index` to access the array element.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var result = arr.map(function(x, i) {
    if(x >= 2) {
        return x + 10;
    } else {
        return x - 10;
    }
});

console.log(result); // [12, 13, 14, NaN]
```

Answer (score 0):

js `map` function iterate the elements (in your case) not the indexes. Your x varriable is the current element in iteration

```js
    var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    var result = arr.map(function(x) {
        if(x >= 2) {
            return x + 10;
        } else {
            return x - 10;
        }
    });
   
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var result = arr.map(function(val, indx) {
    if(arr[indx] >= 2) {
        return arr[indx] + 10;
    } else {
        return arr[indx] - 10;
    }
});
```

You need to use index not value

or you can do it like a pro

```
 const result = arr.map((val, indx) => {
      return  (val >= 2) ? val+10 : val -10       
    });
```

Comment: Degrading readability is for a pro (what about arrow functions) ?

Comment: Right arrow function can be use here

Comment: Return statement and brackets are redundant. However, this is not my point. Personally I think your 'pro' solutions is far less readable than the first one.

Comment: @GuyT here I'm not talking about new syntax but about functional way as he is using `arr[indx] + 10`

Answer (score 0):

`x` in your code is actually referencing an item of your array, not an index.

You can re-write your code as follows:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var result = arr.map( x => (x >= 2) ? x+10 : x-10 )
console.log(result)  // [-9, 12, 13, 14]
```